# Custom Attribute and value not Appearing in Flat Product table if Attribute is not in...Product Listing,Product Listing,Layered Navigation

Tags: magento-1.9, product, attributes, eav, flat-catalog

Basically I installed one market place module in my website......that have a validation attribute...but which is not ...Product Listing,Product Listing,Layered Navigation...so when I use Flat Product ...its attributes and its value is not going in flat product tables...so due to not availability of attribute I can not validate my setting....

```
My attributes setting values..
----------------------------

class VES_VendorsProduct_Model_Source_Approval extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Attribute_Source_Abstract
{
    const STATUS_NOT_SUBMITED   = 0;
    const STATUS_PENDING        = 1;
    const STATUS_APPROVED       = 2;
    const STATUS_UNAPPROVED     = 3;

    static public function getOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            self::STATUS_NOT_SUBMITED   => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Not Submited'),
            self::STATUS_PENDING        => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Pending'),
            self::STATUS_APPROVED       => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Approved'),
            self::STATUS_UNAPPROVED     => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Not Approved')
        );
    }

    public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return array(
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Not Submited'),
                'value' =>  self::STATUS_NOT_SUBMITED
            ),
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Pending'),
                'value' =>  self::STATUS_PENDING
            ),
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Approved'),
                'value' =>  self::STATUS_APPROVED
            ),
            array(
                'label' => Mage::helper('vendors')->__('Not Approved'),
                'value' =>  self::STATUS_UNAPPROVED
            ),
        );
    }
}


My validation In List.php block
---------------------------------
$collection->addAttributeToFilter('approval',VES_VendorsProduct_Model_Source_Approval::STATUS_APPROVED);
```

so problem is this ...the value of this is not avail in flat table....its working fine  with eav...but not fine with flat tables.....so how can i solve this issue...how can i get attribute value by product id...with query..or any solution

setting of attribute..
----------------------[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Only the attributes that are marked to be used in product listing are copyed to the flat tables. Mark it like this and reindex everything.

Comment: i did this ..but when  i check by...echo "<pre>";print_r($_productCollection->toArray());...its not showing...

Comment: How can i get that attribute value by query by product id...from eav...also how can i get attribute id of that

Comment: Make sure you cleared the cache. If you marked the product "Used in product listing" it has to be in the flat table.

Comment: champ answer...

Comment: @Marius as I observed that the attribute "ts_dimensions_width" contains "Used in Product Listing" configured as "No" by default M2.3.1CE, but this attribute has been populated in the table "catalog_product_flat_1" is there any idea? please advise