# Flat catalog tables considered a bad practice since M2.1.x and above?

Tags: magento2, best-practice, indexer, flat-catalog

> Magento no longer recommends the use of a flat catalog as a best practice. Continued use of this feature is known to cause performance degradation and other indexing issues. A detailed description and solution is available in the Help Center.
>
> Affected versions include:
>
> - Magento Commerce Cloud 2.1.x and above
> - Magento Commerce (On-Premise) 2.1.x and above
> - Magento Open Source 2.1.x and above

Source: https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/catalog-flat.html

Above link referes to another help page: https://support.magento.com/hc/en-us/articles/360034631192

> Issue Flat indexers can cause:
>
> Heavy SQL load and site performance issues. Long running and stuck
> crons.

**Why is this best practice for large catalogs reversed? Is the heavy SQL load and site performance issues new? Or is it a risk which always was present?
Are there any changes on this topic in the codebase since 2.1.x and above?**

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Starting with Magento 2.3.0+, the use of a flat catalog is no longer a best practice and is not recommended](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/302336/starting-with-magento-2-3-0-the-use-of-a-flat-catalog-is-no-longer-a-best-prac)