# what is a flat catalog in Magento

Tags: catalog, products, flat

I don't really understand **what the flat catalog is?**.

Will it change the appearance of my category pages?

My problem is that the product blocks are all squeezed together looking. Once clicked on, they're ok but really ugly on the category page.

Answer (score 1):

Magento uses the **Entity-Attribute-Value (EAV)** model for storing customer, product, and category data in its database. If you look into database you'll see that there are a lot tables starting with catalog_product_... and catalog_category_... .

Because attributes are stored in many tables, SQL queries can be long and complex for every page you call.

To lighten the load on MySQL and speed up your shop Magento offers flat tables.

For example `catalog_product_flat_1`. If you take a look at the structure of this table you'll see it has a lot of the basic product data which means that, for example in the category product list, only one query has to be executed to this table instead of querying the multiple other tables containing the attribute data.

However, this data is aggregated from the data in the other tables, that means that every time you save a product several `indexes (System > Configuration > Index Management)` are refreshed to compile this product data.

For detailed difference b/w EAV and Flat, kindly [refer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/105343/23943) this.

Answer (score 0):

The Flat Catalog setting only refers to how data is stored in the SQL database. By "flattening" the catalog, it keeps each store's product information in one table instead of spread across many. This can be helpful in many instances.

You may find more information on a similar question here:
[Why and when to use " Flat Catalog"?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105341/why-and-when-to-use-flat-catalog)