# Magento 1.9x occasionally displays unfriendly URLs

Tags: url-rewrite, product-urls

Magento will occasionally display unfriendly URLs even though SEF is enabled in the admin. At first glance, I believe this has something to do with indexing and the order we re-index and refresh caches. Or maybe has something to do with the url_rewrites table growing in size and unable to parse the URL quickly.

Currently using `->getProductUrl()` to get product URL.

[image: unfriendly SE url]

Comment: Magento 1 or Magenti 2 ?

Comment: @Yogesh 1.9x I updated the question.

Comment: You must lunch the indexation

Answer (score 1, accepted):

URL Key is retrieved directly from the database compared to ->getProductUrl() which requires more computation before rendering the final output. Since you're struggling with performance using ->getProductUrl() 
I'd suggest using this one below:

```
$_product->getUrlKey();
```

Comment: Could this be related to the core_url_rewrite table is too big and taking too long to process? It's currently at 25k records.

Comment: @TheRealJAG - It could. Can you check if flat catalog is enabled by navigating to System > Configuration > Catalog > Frontend > Use Flat Catalog Category | Use Flat Catalog Product. Set this to NO.

See more about this and how it affects performance here > https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/105341/why-and-when-to-use-flat-catalog

Comment: Yes we use flat and unable to change.

Comment: @TheRealJAG - I think that's the issue. Flat isn't design to handle big catalog. Any reasons or errors preventing you to change that?